# How can I make tables like in the NPC villages?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In the NPC villages, you can see tables in some of the houses.

How can I create those tables?

Comment: Psst! Pictures!

Comment: Found out it was made with a fence and pressure plate. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3sVS9LSHsG8 around 1:00

Comment: You could have just punched the tables and see what drops.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tables can be made by using a single fence post and then placing a pressure plate on top of it.

Craft the fence like so:

[image: Fence]

And now the pressure plate:

[image: Pressure Plate]

And here is what it should look like:

[image: What it should look like!]
<sub>(source: [minecraftwiki.net](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/images/4/4c/Pressure_plate.png))</sub>

Answer (score 5):

I believe that they can be created by placing a single fence post with a wooden pressure plate on top.